# Apple TV with a household of more than one Apple IDs

Tags: appletv, apple-id

Can you log in more than one account as long as you log off the one that is signed on before signing in another? For instance, if you buy an AppleTV and your house has two other members with different Apple IDs, can each person use the AppleTV as long as the one that is logged on is signed off then another person logs in? Or does it only allow one Apple user use the tv?

Would each person have to own the AppleTV or can more than one family member share one?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible.  You can log out of your Apple TV and have someone else log in.  This can get kind of annoying though. But it is possible.

If you have multiple computers in the house though, each with stuff bought with different Apple IDs, and you just want to access the content on the machines, that is very possible too.  You can set up home sharing with one Apple ID on your Apple TV and then on the rest of the other machines.  It has to be the same ID across the different machines but it will let you access all the computers that are on the network from the Apple TV and access and stream the content stored on them.

You can find a great tutorial [over here](http://www.amandahackwith.com/?p=227).

You can still do things the old fashion way and log out and log back in, it can just be kind of tedious.  Home Sharing can really simplify the process if you just want to share content from multiple computers though.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple TV software update 5.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4448) allows for multiple Apple ID accounts to be entered and easy switching between them. This makes family and workplace use much nicer in my opinion. The old way of signing out was painful in practice to do more than as seldom as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think they key is Airplay, if you use the AppleTV as your starting point, then it will only connect via homeshare etc to a single user ID at a time without changing the login, which is a pain if you have a decent password.  But if you take your devices as the starting point, then using your iPod/Pad/Phone or Mac and searching for Airplay compatible receivers, then you can push the content without having to make changes at the AppleTV end.